# Mass Sorting Script

Tags: python, sorting

I have a long list of items that I have the numbers on the wrong side and can't think of how to get this done. Every line that I want sorted is formatted like this

```
blahblah - number
```

but I want them to be like this

```
number - blahblah
```

Edited it to make it understandable for people searching for this.

Comment: Answering questions for python AND cpp is... very difficult... unless you want a cpp extension to python... Can you narrow the scope a little? What are you trying to do; if you're just trying to sort lists and don't know how to program, I would suspect dumping into excel would be fastest for you :)

Comment: I took out python because I would rather C++ but I just thought python would be the language to use because of what I have heard.

Comment: Okay, well this is a little unfortunate now because you have two working solutions as answers, but in the wrong language :) In the future, I'd tag with the language that you want, not the one you want to want :)

Comment: Vesche's answer worked with very little knowledge of python so I re tagged it and apologize for not giving a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `whatever.txt` to the filename of your data.

```
with open('whatever.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ' '.join(line.split()[::-1])
```

Comment: hah this is easier than mine :) good job +1

Comment: why f.read().splitlines() instead of f.readlines()?

Comment: Thanks that was very easy to use without almost any python experience sorry about being so hard to understand with what I wanted.

Comment: Why `for line in data:` instead of `for line in f:`?

Comment: @en_Knight I've made it a habit to use `f.read().splitlines()` instead of `f.readlines()` because it strips off line breaks, it's much cleaner to use. For example, `'ab c\n\nde fg\rkl\r\n'.splitlines()` returns `['ab c', '', 'de fg', 'kl']` instead of `['ab c\n', '\n', 'de fg\r', 'kl\r\n']` which is what `readlines()` would return.

Comment: @zondo Thanks, that is cleaner. The `splitlines()` and `split()` were somewhat redundant.

Comment: Just how you have it won't quite work, though.  You should use `line.rstrip().split()[::-1]`.

Comment: @zondo That shouldn't make a difference `"1 - a\n".split()` will return `['1', '-', 'a']`

Comment: Ah yes; I forgot. :/

Answer (score 1):

this is python (which you had this tagged as)

```
import fileinput,re
for line in fileinput.input("path/to/file.txt"):
    print re.sub("(.*)\s*-\s*(.*)","\\2 - \\1",line)
```

hmm you deleted the python tag ... so im not sure this is applicable still ...

Comment: I deleted it because I know C++ and would be able to understand it more if someone was trying to help me but I will try this once I get python on my system. One question does the version matter will this work with both?

Comment: no this is python2 ... for python3 I think you would just say `print(re.sub...)`

Comment: Haha Joran I'm sure this works, but for someone who doesn't know *any* python I can't image this being comprehensible. Of course, someone who doesn't know python probably shouldn't tag a question as python...

Comment: I like to help people broaden their horizons :P

Comment: Well it worked - I've never heard of fileinput before